# What is the error in this simple C Shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

The code is supposed to take an hour as input and then say good morning, afternoon, or evening.
When the code is run with 12 it says if statement syntax error, but it works fine with 0.

```
#!/bin/csh  
#
# Time of day greeting
#
# usage: greet [hour between 0-23]
#
if ($#argv == 0) then
   set hour = 'date +%H'
   else
     set hour = $argv[1]
endif
#
if ($hour < 12) then
echo "Good Morning\!"
else
if (hour < 18) then
echo "Good Afternoon\!"
else
echo "Good Evening\!"
endif
endif
#
exit 0
#
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second `if` statement doesn't have a dollar sign in front of `hour`.